# Add minutes to datetime in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is there a function in Hive one could use to add minutes(in int) to a datetime similar to `DATEADD (datepart,number,date)`in sql server where `datepart` can be `minutes`:
`DATEADD(minute,2,'2014-07-06 01:28:02')` returns `2014-07-06 01:28:02`
On the other hand, Hive's `date_add(string startdate, int days)` is in `days`. Any of such for `hours`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem can easily solve by HiveUdf.

```
package HiveUDF;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

public class addMinuteUdf extends UDF{
    final long ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS=60000;
    private  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    public String evaluate(String t, int minute) throws ParseException{
        long time=formatter.parse(t.toString()).getTime();
        Date AddingMins=new Date(time + (minute * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));
        String date = formatter.format(AddingMins);
        return date;
    }
}
```

After creating AddMinuteUdf.jar , Register it in Hive;

```
ADD JAR /home/Kishore/AddMinuteUdf.jar; 
create temporary FUNCTION addMinute as 'HiveUDF.addMinuteUdf';


hive> select date from ATable;
OK
2014-07-06 01:28:02
Time taken: 0.108 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

After applying function

```
hive> select addMinuteUdf(date, 2) from ATable;     
OK
2014-07-06 01:30:02
Time taken: 0.094 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 25):

Instead of using UDF, you can add seconds to datetime, converted it to unix_timestamp() and then convert the result back to datetime.

Example:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-12-12 16:15:17')+3600);
```

Here we added one hour:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-11-12 12:15:17')+${seconds_in_hour});
OK
2015-11-12 13:15:17
Time taken: 0.121 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

So, in case of minutes addition you shall add number of minutes*60.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you, Sergey!

Comment: Using this you will lose milisecond info of timestamp. better to go with UDF based approach