# date with 23:59:59 in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I've got to pull the records between yesterday date starting 00:00:00 to end of hour 23:59:59.

I got the yesterday date as follows

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24, 'dd-MMM-yy');
```

However, I am not sure how to get to 23:59:59 in hive.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399544/add-minutes-to-datetime-in-hive) SO ( 1 year old) answer , it is achievable using hive UDF.

I wonder if there is a simple way such as using a build in function to do so.

Answer (score 1):

We need only playing with the unixtime

```
select 
from_unixtime(datediff(current_date, '1970-01-01')*3600*24-3600, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') 
as start_time,
from_unixtime(datediff(current_date, '1970-01-00')*3600*24-3600-1, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') 
as end_time
```

And we get:
[image]

Comment: I noticed that above query gives start_time as 24-05-2016 19:00:00  and end_time as 25-05-2016 18:59:59. I tweaked query a little bit as follows to get the correct start_time ( 24-05-2016 00:00:00) and end_time(25-05-2016 23:59:59). 'select from_unixtime(datediff(current_date, '1970-01-01')*60*60*24-72000, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') 
as start_time,
from_unixtime(datediff(current_date, '1970-01-00')*60*60*24+14399, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') 
as end_time;'

Comment: @Arun It seems that it depend to the timezone ! Thank you, I have learned something new.

Comment: Could you update query with timezone and test it. I can mark as correct answer. thanks for your help.