# All Hive functions fail

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, beeline

I honestly don't know what is going on. Everything fails except basically `SHOW DATABASES`.

Nothing on this page (below) even works. Everything gives me a NoViableAltException. This is both in Hive and Beeline CLI.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

My opinion is I shouldn't have to be connected to a DB to execute these commands which didn't initially work. But, I decided to try connecting to the default DB and still all the same failures. Created a new DB and same failures. Sources I've used for doc info...

http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html

http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/difference-between-normal-tables-and.html

http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Hortonworks.CheatSheet.SQLtoHive.pdf

[Add minutes to datetime in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399544/add-minutes-to-datetime-in-hive)

Nothing works. All NoViableAltException exception. I started the cloudera manger and all things check healthy except Impala. I'm using the CDH5 quickstart docker image. Tried both hive and beeline cli. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is an example from another StackOverflow question that fails though different exception.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'from_unixtime' '(' 'unix_timestamp' (state=42000,code=40000)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default>
```

This one is a different exception but I can't get anything other than show databases/tables/etc to work.

Here is another...

```
hive> DATEDIFF('2000-03-01', '2000-01-10');
NoViableAltException(26@[])
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:626)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'DATEDIFF' '(' ''2000-03-01''
```

Literally nothing I see on the net that should work works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add SELECT.

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());

SELECT  DATEDIFF('2000-03-01', '2000-01-10');
```

Comment: How I didn't come across this I have no idea. I should have known better. Say I wanted to use a "datediff" as a value in a where clause. Would I have to execute it as `(SELECT  DATEDIFF('2000-03-01', '2000-01-10'))`?

Comment: You would have to wrap the statement you want to use the WHERE clause with, and SELECT from that. e.g. `SELECT inside.colName FROM (SELECT DATEDIFF('2000-03-01', '2000-01-10') AS colName) inside WHERE inside.colName = 51;`