# Hive SQL- Adding (not appending) seconds to an existing time stamp

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp

I am trying to add seconds to an existing time stamp to find the end time. 
I have start time in one field and total duration in one field. How could i add. i tried to use  date_add function, but that dont work.

```
Select
      testdate, 
      DATE_ADD ( testdate,CAST (testduration as INT) ) as Test_end_date  
from <DBName>  limit 10;
TestDate is this format= 9/14/2017 16:33:25.000000
Testduration is in seconds e.g: 144 seconds or so
```

It adds to the date rather than to the seconds component.

Any help is appreciated.

Tried Date_Add function, wont work.

Comment: Possible duplicate... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399544/add-minutes-to-datetime-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

Convert to seconds using unix_timestamp, add seconds

```
select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('9/14/2017 16:33:25.000000','M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSS')+144, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS')
```

This returns timestamp in standard Hive timestamp format, change output format if you need to keep original one: 'M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSS' as a second parameter of `from_unixtime()` function.