# Substract the hour from the timestamp.( hour is part of the timestamp column)

Tags: hive, hiveql

Need some help to perform this in Hive .
I do have timestamp like `"2019-03-11T18:23:49-04:00"`
How to I subtract the hour and minutes from the above timestamp.( `-04:00`) 
The hour component may vary based on the timezone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -04:00 is a timezone and hour is 18:23? Do you need to extract timezone or hour:minutes? Do you need to convert to another timezone? Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't do this as easily as you can in MSSQL with dateadd. Some very good suggestions are made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399544/add-minutes-to-datetime-in-hive). I also tested this and it works as it should.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-12-12 16:15:17')+8500)
```

I have modified this to work with your exact timestamp format

```
select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(substring(translate("2019-03-11T18:23:49-04:00",'T',' '),1,19))+8500)
```